# Typescript baseUrl not affecting module resolution in VS Code

Tags: typescript, path, visual-studio-code

Given the project described below, I get the following errors:

```
[ts] Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

[tslint] Module 'Enums' is not listed as dependency in package.json (no-implicit-dependencies)
```

The folder structure of the project I have open in VS Code:

```
root/
-- tsconfig.json
-- src/
---- web/
------ src/
-------- ts/
---------- Navbar.ts (with exported namespace "Navbar")
---------- Shared/
------------ Other.ts
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src/web/src/ts/"
    }
}
```

Navbar Module in Navbar.ts:

```
export namespace Navbar {
   export class NavbarHandler {
       ...
   }
}
```

Importing Navbar in Other.ts:

```
import { Navbar } from "Navbar";

const navbar = new Navbar.NavbarHandler();
```

As far as I can tell, my baseUrl is correct and is being recognized by VS Code - as VS Code shows the correct module path for Navbar when i hover over `"Navbar"` in Other.ts.

Have I made a mistake? Is there something I'm not accounting for or I'm missing in my config?

Answer (score 2):

You have this error because of `no-implicit-dependencies` rule in your tslint config.

Currently there is no option to configure this rule to work with relative path. So, if you want to work with relative paths - you would need to disable this rule. Put `"no-implicit-dependencies": false` in your `tslint.json` file.

Here are on-going discussions about making this rule be configurable:
https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3364, 
https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3483

[Here](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3364#issuecomment-376881389) you also can find some hacky workaround.